# SharePoint calculated conditional formula to return zero if column is zero

Tags: sharepoint

I have calculated date formula for Projected NVSMR column:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Last NVMSR])+[3yr], MONTH([Last NVMSR]), DAY([Last NVMSR]))
```

Which is great. But, I also want it to return zero if the 3yr column equals zero.  I have tried  different `DATEDIFF`'s and just `IF` formulas and SharePoint returns `#NUM` for all members listed or Syntax error.

I am the awards monitor and only certain individuals are allowed a three year award.  If they are not allowed a three year award I want to enter "0" and have "0" return in the Projected NVMSR column "0".

Answer (score 0):

What you need is IF(TEST,TRUE,FALSE) - see this [SharePoint Calculated Column Cheat Sheet](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/sharepoint-calculated-column-cheat-sheet/) for quick reference and examples.

So

```
=IF([3yr]=0,0,DATE(YEAR([Last NVMSR])+[3yr], MONTH([Last NVMSR]), DAY([Last NVMSR])))
```

Or formatted for easy reading

```
=IF( [3yr] = 0,
     0,
     DATE(YEAR([Last NVMSR])+[3yr], MONTH([Last NVMSR]), DAY([Last NVMSR]))
   )
```